# Problem compiler error about figure/subfigure ' caption using latex IEEE ACCESS template

Tags: floats, captions, templates, subfig

In IEEE ACCESS template latex file, there is a example code of "\Figure", when inserting pictures into paper.

But I want to use figure and subfigure environment to fit my requirement. So I add usepackage of "subfigure" and "caption", except for losing figure's caption color it works well.  If I cancel the usagepackage of "caption", compiler error occurs:  "**Undefined control sequence. \caption{Universe}**"

How I can use figure and subfigure which shows correctly and normally(with color caption) in my paper? (I am using **MikTex** and **Texstudio** in **Windows10**)

Following is the source code of latex file and error picture.

[image]

*IEEE ACCESS template is* [here](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-ieee-access/).

**latex source code:**

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}  % support sub-figure

% compiler error without following two lines
%\usepackage{caption,setspace}
%\captionsetup{font={small,stretch=0.80}}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

hese instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for 
IEEE Access. Use this document as a template if you are 
using \LaTeX. Otherwise, use this document as an 
instruction set. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Figure, Float, SubFigure

\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are 
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the 
electronic file \ref{fig:universe}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{universe.jpg}
    \caption{Universe}
    \label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Are you forced by a journal using that class? If yes, I think they will not accept papers not using there template, so do not change it ... Ask if you are allowed to change the template ...

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete for over ten years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are allowed to change the template, you can use the `labelfont` key in `\captionsetup` to set the color. Finding the latter took some digging in the code of the class. I also took the freedom to set the fonts according to the template (`sf` and `bf`).

[image]

The code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}  % support sub-figure

% compiler error without following two lines
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\captionsetup{font={sf,small,stretch=0.80},labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

hese instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for 
IEEE Access. Use this document as a template if you are 
using \LaTeX. Otherwise, use this document as an 
instruction set. 
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Figure, Float, SubFigure

\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. If you are 
reading a paper or PDF version of this document, please download the 
electronic file \ref{fig:universe}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image.png}
    \caption{Universe}
    \label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\Figure[h]()[scale=0.2]{example-image.png}{Universe}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete package.its supersede is  `subfig`. or use `subcaption`.

Answer (score 12):

They provide a new command to handle the images in IEEE Access. I show you an example.

```
\Figure[!t]()[width=0.95\textwidth]{imageName}
   {Caption.\label{fig:label}}
```

This command puts the image using two columns or one column automatically. It depends on the figure's dimension. If it is lower than 50%, the figure is put in one column, else in two columns.

Comment: How can I centre the figure?

Comment: it is not need to centre the figure, in the ieee access  style file is pre-defined to be centered. For instance, all my images are centered in my document using the \Figure command without using \centering command

Comment: This is good for single images, but I don't there exist a preset thing for subfigures yet.

Comment: How can I fit into a page while I use [width=0.95\textwidth] ? If I add height info into bracket like that  [width=0.95\textwidth, height = 1\pageheight] it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

for plotting subfigures i used the code in the IEEE access template and it works. I included the following packages

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption,setspace}
\captionsetup{font={sf,small,stretch=0.80},labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    %\vspace*{-.02in}
    \subfloat[Performance comparison when x=t]{
        \hspace*{-.1in}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{fig1.pdf}
        \hspace*{-.1in}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{fig2.pdf}
        \label{p_D_req_100}
    }
    %   \vspace*{-.14in}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Performance comparison when x=u]{
        \hspace*{-.1in}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{fig3.pdf}
        \hspace*{-.1in}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{fig4.pdf}
        \label{p_D_req_400}
    }
    %   \vspace*{-.14in}
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Performance comparison when x=z]{
        \hspace*{-.1in}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{fig5.pdf}
        \hspace*{-.1in}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.33]{fig6.pdf}
        \label{p_D_req_1000}
    }
    \caption{the EE (left) and  xxxx  (right) of cat cat cat load.}
    \label{fig:p_graph}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: I guess there is no way to extract the caption setup etc from the template directly?

Answer (score 1):

According to Section IV.I.2 of the IEEE Access template,

> Multipart figures should be combined and labeled before
>   final submission. Labels should appear centered below each
>   subfigure in 8 point Times New Roman font in the format of
>   (a) (b) (c).

Such a subfigure feature is not supported by IEEE Access template.

Comment: In June 2021, the section IV.B says: > Figures compiled of more than one sub-figure presented side-by-side, or stacked. If a multipart figure is made up of multiple figure
types (one part is lineart, and another is grayscale or color) the figure
should meet the stricter guidelines.